# Setting column width in Table View

Tags: android

I am having a hard time understanding how to change the width of columns when creating a table view.

I know you can set the width in pixels of a column but that is not what I want to do.

Say, for instance, I have 2 columns and want each column to take up half the screen. How do I do this without explicitly setting the pixels, so that my code can work on multiple screen sizes?

Answer (score 3):

With a `TableLayout`? You can't do that easily. The closest you can get is to use `android:stretchColumns="*"` on your `TableLayout` element. That should allocate any *extra* whitespace evenly between the two columns.

Comment: Maybe I'm not using the right terminology. I'm creating a table, is there a way for a specific set of coloumns to make them span the entire screen evenly?

Comment: you would have to do that with a horizontal linear layout for each row with the layout_weight controlling the width. However that does not play nicely once the content varies..

Answer (score 0):

Just set the TableRow layout_width="0dip"
and then set the two column layout_weight="1"
This will help you evenly divide a row.